# Read emails on Tomcat: ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException

Tags: maven, email, tomcat, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

My application is running on Tomcat 7.

I'm trying to read emails from inbox, and for that I use a normal Java class.

There is also a Servlet that calls the method `readMails` in the mentioned class.

Now I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
...
```

I use IntelliJ IDEA with Maven, I changed the dependency of javax.mail a lot (see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail), but the exception keeps coming up.

I've also changed the Version of Tomcat (7 and 8), and the version of "Project SDK" (1.7 and 1.8) and "Project language level" (7 and 8).

I've read somewhere that there is a difference between reading emails via IMAP with normal Java application and running it on Tomcat.

In a previous project I read emails successfully with a normal Java application.

Can anyone help me with this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

to my pom.xml. This way maven puts the dependencies in the target folder.

Answer (score 1):

JavaMail API is not included by default among Tomcat libraries.

Make sure that JavaMail dependency (mail-X.X.jar) is either packaged together with your application (in WEB-INF/lib) or is in a folder that Tomcat class loaders read (for example $CATALINA_HOME/lib), as described here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works now.

I put the jar file (**javax.mail: javax.mail-api-1.5.4.jar**) downloaded by maven (.m2/repository/ ...) into **WEB-INF/lib** (in my project).

I also needed to put another jar file into WEB-INF/lib (**com.sun.mail: javax.mail-1.5.4.jar**) due to this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger
    javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:226)
    javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:210)
    javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:321)
```